# Is there a way not to call the subclass method when invoking?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclass

I wanted to create my own database program in Java. I know that there are already solutions out there like sylite etc., but I want to do it myself. As it turned out to be a more complex program than first expected, I used a lot of inheritance to keep the overview. For example:

- The first class is the `RawStreamManager` to handle the Stream to a File using `FileOutputStream`
- The second class is the `SessionManager` in order to prevent multiple access using some kind of csma/cd strategy
- There are a some more classes to do other things.

My problem now, however, is that the `SessionManager` would use the `read()` method of a subclass, instead of its own, when I call e.g. the method `read()`. I guess there is a good reason for that, but in my case it makes no sense to figure out weather the client has the authority and to split the String into a database, when the client does not have the Token (the allowance to read/write without multiple access). So I´m looking for a way to call the `read()` method of `SessionManager` (there are a few more cases for which I would Need that) instead of the subclasses `read()` method

I already tried to manually cast the `SessionManager` to a `SessionManager` object before calling `read()`, but that didn't help.
A kind of Workaround could be to give those methods a different Name.

To Show you guys some code without dropping my hole Database-Code here I simplified the Problem:

```java
public class First {
    public First() {
        System.out.println("syso from first:");
        ((First) this).print();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("FIRST");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Second extends First{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Second();
    }

    public Second() {
        System.out.println("syso from second:");
        print();
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        super.print();
        System.out.println("SECOND");
    }
}
```

now I would expect the Output to be:

```
syso from first:
FIRST
syso from second:
FIRST
SECOND
```

but it is (3rd line):

```
syso from first:
FIRST
SECOND
syso from second:
FIRST
SECOND
```

So, has anyone of u a solution for that problem please? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating an instance of the `Second` class, when the constructor of `Second` is invoked a call to the super class constructor `First()` is invoked implicitly sue to the implicit invocation of `super()` in the `Second()` call.

Although you have type casted `this` to `First` it will still invoke the overriden method of the `Second` class due to the nature of *dynamic/runtime polymorphism* in Java. At runtime, JVM checks the instance and calls its method not of the reference.

To avoid and give the expected output you need to make the print method static or use a different method name altogether:

```
class First {
    public First() {
        System.out.println("syso from first:");
        First.print();
    }

    public static void print() {
        System.out.println("FIRST");
    }
}
 class Second extends First{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Second();
    }

    public Second() {
        System.out.println("syso from second:");
        Second.print();
    }


    public static void print() {
        First.print();
        System.out.println("SECOND");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
syso from first:
FIRST
syso from second:
FIRST
SECOND
```

The static version gives the expected output as the method in the case of static *belongs* to the class rather than the instance. In the class `Second` I have *hidden* and not overriden the `print()` of the base class `First`.

Comment: Tanks a Million! That hits the nail. But is it so unpopular to code a program in smaller modules to keep the overview or is it just me scrued up at some point of my program? That can´t be a popular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Amardeep Bhowmick answer, there might be some instances where you might not want that method as static. I believe the problem itself is more about the code organization. Avoid method invocation in the class constructor itself:

```
public class First {
    public First() {
        System.out.println("syso from first:");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("FIRST");
    }
}

public class Second extends First{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Second();
    }

    public Second() {
        super.print();
        System.out.println("syso from second:");
        this.print();
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        super.print();
        System.out.println("SECOND");
    }
}
```

The only difference is that you call your function outside the constructor instead of the moment you instantiate `First`, for example with `new First().print()`